# ASP.NET Dynamic Data? Real world user admin application

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I need to develop a user admin application.

My schema looks like the following:

[image]

[See full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuH4O.gif)

As you can see I've got my own version of the user table and profile tables to store my data with a one-to-one mapping with aspnet membership tables.

I'm interested in using ASP.NET dynamics to speed up the proccess of creating an admin system.

I would like to create a customised listing with a search and a data grid listing with just basic details such as name and state information, date registered and then when you click to edit your presented with the domain representation of the data and not the exact undelying data.

Has anyone any experiece in doing this or building a real work application with Dynamic data?

Any tip suggestion, alternative etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone any experience in doing this or building a real work application with Dynamic data?

Yes I have several systems that use a Hybryd of DD anf Membership to manage users.